# Hadoop User Classpath - Beeline

Tags: apache-spark, hive, beeline

Is there any way I can set HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST for beeline MapReduce and spark engines

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/xx/jackson/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:/xx/jackson/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:/xx/jackson/jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar

set mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true;
```

I am able to get this working with hive-cli and mr engine but its not working with beeline and mr engine and also with spark engine

Answer (score 0):

Ok I could figure out for MapReduce engine

With below config, it works whereas for hive on spark, I am not yet successful

CM > Hive > Configuration > search for "Hive Service Environment Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve)"

```
HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/xx/jackson/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:/xx/jackson/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:/xx/jackson/jackson-annotations-2.6.1.jar
```

Comment: Don't mix jackson JARs from different jackson versions, it will only disappoint.